# errorformat settings for gcc in german environment

Tags: gcc, vim, makefile

Within english environment the error messages are as follows:

> make[5]: Entering directory '/home/krud/git_my_checkout/first/project_m'
>
> make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/krud/git_my_checkout/first/project_m'

With german environment, the output from make with gcc looks like:

> make[5]: Verzeichnis „/home/krud/git_my_checkout/first/project_m“ wird betreten
>
> make[5]: Verzeichnis „/home/krud/git_my_checkout/first/project_m“ wird verlassen

I added the following to my `.vimrc` file:

```
set errorformat+=
      \%D%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ betreten,
      \%X%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ verlassen,
```

But the directory will not be catched.

The same result if I add this lines to `./vim80/compiler/gcc.vim`

if exists("current_compiler")
      finish
    endif
    let current_compiler = "gcc"

```
let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

CompilerSet errorformat=
      \%*[^\"]\"%f\"%*\\D%l:%c:\ %m,
      \%*[^\"]\"%f\"%*\\D%l:\ %m,
      \\"%f\"%*\\D%l:%c:\ %m,
      \\"%f\"%*\\D%l:\ %m,
      \%-G%f:%l:\ %trror:\ (Each\ undeclared\ identifier\ is\ reported\ only\ once,
      \%-G%f:%l:\ %trror:\ for\ each\ function\ it\ appears\ in.),
      \%f:%l:%c:\ %trror:\ %m,
      \%f:%l:%c:\ %tarning:\ %m,
      \%f:%l:%c:\ %m,
      \%f:%l:\ %trror:\ %m,
      \%f:%l:\ %tarning:\ %m,
      \%f:%l:\ %m,
      \%f:\\(%*[^\\)]\\):\ %m,
      \\"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%*\\D%c%*[^\ ]\ %m,
      \%D%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Entering\ directory\ [`']%f',
      \%X%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Leaving\ directory\ [`']%f',
      \%D%*\\a:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ betreten,
      \%X%*\\a:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ verlassen,
      \%D%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ betreten,
      \%X%*\\a[%*\\d]:\ Verzeichnis\ [`„]%f“\ wird\ verlassen,
      \%D%*\\a:\ Entering\ directory\ [`']%f',
      \%X%*\\a:\ Leaving\ directory\ [`']%f',
      \%DMaking\ %*\\a\ in\ %f

if exists('g:compiler_gcc_ignore_unmatched_lines')
  CompilerSet errorformat+=%-G%.%#
endif
```

Any idea what is wrong with my errorformat settings?